# Can multiple observables post to the same topic in knockout pubsub

Tags: knockout.js, publish-subscribe

I am using knockout's native publish/subscribe support. I understand that I need to do the following to post to/read from a topic:

```
var postbox = ko.subscribable();
var vendorTopic = 'vendorInfo';

//View model 1
//Subscribe
ko.subscribable.fn.subscribeTo = function(topic) {
    postbox.subscribe(this, null, topic);
    return this;  //support chaining
};
this.selectedVendor = ko.observableArray().subscribeTo(vendorTopic);

//View model 2
//Publish
ko.subscribable.fn.publishOn = function (topic) {
    this.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        postbox.notifySubscribers(newValue,topic);
    });
    return this; //support chaining
};
this.vendor = ko.observableArray([]).publishOn(vendorTopic);
```

But, if my viewmodel2 had 2 observables and I want to be able to access both of them in my viewmodel1, do I need to create two topics - one for each observable? That sounds like a bad design if say my component has 15 observables that I want to use in another component.

But I couldn't find any other useful example on the internet. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just a thought, we should be able to send an array of objects containing the new values of the observables in a key - value pair fashion, and then inside of the viewmodel1 we can parse the object, right?

Answer (score 0):

As @gkb comments, you could pass a complex object with all your needed values.

For your code, I assume that you are using [knockout-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) or at least getting code snippets from the author's blog ([knockmeout](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html)), in which case, you need to sync each observable using a different topic for each one.

```
let vm1 ={
   prop1:ko.observable().syncWith('prop1'),
   prop2:ko.observable().syncWith('prop2'),
   prop3:ko.observable().syncWith('prop3'),
};

let vm2 ={
   prop2:ko.observable().syncWith('prop2'),
}

let vm3 ={
   prop1:ko.observable().syncWith('prop1'),
   prop2:ko.observable().syncWith('prop2'),
   prop3:ko.observable().syncWith('prop3'),
}
```

In this example, every property will be synchronized in all viewmodels.